# Amdahl's law of processors (infinite processors to test limits of speedup)

Tags: parallel-computing

My processor noted that an **infinite number of processors will allow me to test how much speedup I can achieve.**

I am not exactly sure how this applies.

For instance, let's say I have a program that takes $1000$ seconds to execute and is broken into 4 phases(A, B, C, D). If two of the phases are $50%$ parallelizable and the other $2$ are not parallelizable at all, how can I apply the concept that I have infinite available processors to figure out how much maximum speed up I can achieve?

I attached numbers to my example, but a generic one would be just as helpful.

If I am to strictly just apply Amdahl's law, I'd say the answer is just $1/(1-0.5) = 2$ times faster.

Comment: When you say that it's "50 parallelizable", do you mean that two of the phases can be sped up 50 times due to parallelization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of it as "you've been given infinity processors." Think of it as "you can have as many processors as you want, but of course after a certain point more professors won't help, so find out how fast you can make it run with the optimum number of processors."

Comment: I have added my attempt at the answer. Am I on the right track? I do understand what you're saying about the optimum # of procs, because at a certain point the serialization for the processes overpowers the gain from parallelization.

Comment: Heh. "... after a certain point, more professors won't help ...". That's always been my experience.